# Sharepoint 2013 Document last modified date code snippet

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am using sharepoint 2013.  I have a page that does not show the document library itself, but has links to documents within it.  Next to the link I would like to show the date the document was last modified for each file.  See image[image: Screenshot of the links]

The text is not a link, just the PDF is a link to a file with in a document library.  They are not all in the same library though, some are on other sharepoint 2013 sites, that I own as well.

Is this even possible?  I have been searching for a few days, but have not found anything close to what I am looking to do.  Most of what I am finding is related to getting the date in applications outside of sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible depending upon the SharePoint api you use and the location of documents.
If using SharePoint JSOM, its possible if all the sites in which documents are stored are is same site collection.

If using SharePoint object model and using correct privileges, there's no limitation whether the documents are is same or different site collections (you may have to use different context objects though)

Comment: I am not sure which API model my company uses.  They are in different site collections.  How do I do it?

Comment: use SharePoint server object model